# What properties do isospectral Riemannian manifolds share?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, spectral-theory, laplacian

I'm studying the Laplacian on (compact) Riemannian manifolds, and it turns out that if the Laplacian operators of two such spaces share their spectrum (the spaces are then called **isospectral**), then the spaces themselves must share some geometric properties. The most spectacular I've come across is that if two Riemannian manifolds are isospectral, then they share their sequence of lengths of closed geodesics. What other properties do they share? I'd really appreciate references on these, so I could look up the  proofs.

So far I've looked at Buser's textbook "Geometry and Spectra of Compact Riemann Surfaces", and [some notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~canzani/math253.html) by Yaiza Canzani for a course at Harvard. Between them they mention the closed geodesic lengths, as well as shared volume, dimension, and total Ricci curvature (so for surfaces, the same Euler characteristic, meaning that they are diffeomorphic assuming compactness).

Comment: Where have you looked? If  you are studying this, you have surely looked at textbooks and or surveys on the subject. It will cut down duplication of effort if you took the time to tell potential answerers what you know already! (In general, requests of the form «tell me about X» (which in particular are not questions) are not a great fit to the question&answer format of this site)